# What library do I need for 'pg_connect()'?

Tags: php, wordpress, postgresql

I'm trying to connect to another database within a wordpress plugin. Inside the main php file, I tried to call 'pg_connect($con_string);' but I now realize that this function is undefined. Is there a library that I need to include somewhere in the directory? Thanks.

Comment: What `main.php` file? We have no idea what you're trying to do. We need more information.

Comment: I am not able to use the pg_connect() function and I believe the reason is that I do not have either the correct extensions for it or library. The only thing in the php file is the pg connect line. Sorry, I am a beginner to postgresql. I just have no idea what I need to do in order to have access to the connect function.

Answer (score 3):

This function is in the `php-pgsql` package or module. Not sure what OS you are on, but on some Linux distributions the package has version-specific naming like `php5-pgsql` or `php7-pgsql` so you might need to install the version specific to whatever PHP version you're using. You can use `phpinfo()` to output information that will help you troubleshooot what is going on, including versions and what packages are enabled.

The package may need to be installed, or it may be installed but disabled. It is enabled by default in PHP >= 5.3.x. If you're finding it is not included by default, you likely either have a *very old* version of PHP, or one that is custom-configured not to have this package enabled.

If the issue is enabling it, look in the configuration files. On some systems there is a file installed in `/etc/php.d/` like `20-pgsql.ini` with a line that will enable the extension. In other systems it is in `php.ini` which is usually somewhere in the `/etc` directory. Search these files for a line containing the text `pgsql` and make sure it is enabled. Then restart the web server (or PHP-FPM if you are using that.)

Hopefully this will address the issue.

If you need further help, the official PostgreSQL documentation is a good resource:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_php.htm

And beyond that I would recommend a web search including your specific distribution and possibly PHP version, as this will return information with the correct configuration file locations and options.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. I guess the main problem is that my website is not hosted on the same server where the database I'm trying to access is, so I don't have the option to do the install commands.

Comment: @Swaginator09 The package needs to be installed and configured on the webserver, i.e. the one where the PHP script is. If you cannot control this server, or cannot get its administrator to install and/or enable the package, it may not be possible to use the function. However, it does not need to be on the server running the database: PHP is able to connect remotely to a PostgreSQL database easily.